# Use Clusterize.js in Angular project

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the Clusterize.js library in my Angular project (https://clusterize.js.org/).

I have never imported an external js library in projects, and I am failing trying what I found on the web (add module, place in assets, load in index.html...). Always errors like module Clusterize not found, undefined, or constructor not defined etc...

How to implement Clusterize.js ? What are the best practices ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to use an external JavaScript library in an Angular project is :

**Declare JavaScript file in angular.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": [
    "node_modules/clusterize/clusterize.min.js"
  ]
}
```

**Import it in your TypeScript file as module**

`import * as Clusterize from 'clusterize';`